# '-' not working while using Regular Expressions to match special characters, c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Pattern is

```
Regex splRegExp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[\,@,+,\,?,\d,%,.,?,*,&,^,$,(,!,),#,-,_]");
```

All characters work except '-'. Please advise.

Comment: Why all the commas? They are treated as a "standard" character not as separators, so they are "matched" (`[,]` matches the `,`). And be aware that the `\` escapes the next character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
@"[,@+\\?\d%.*&^$(!)#_-]"
```

No need for all those commas.

If you place a `-` inside a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), it means a literal dash only if it's at the start or end of the class. Otherwise it denotes a range like `A-Z`. As Damien put it, the range `,-,` is indeed rather small (and doesn't contain the `-`, of course).

Comment: I was trying to work out the best way to say that he sure did want `,` to be in that character group, and that the range `,-,` is rather small, but you seem to have adequately summed things up.

Answer (score 1):

'-' has to be the first charater in your regex.

```
Regex splRegExp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[-,\,@,+,\,?,\d,%,.,?,*,&,^,$,(,!,),#,_]");
```

Comment: Or you can "escape" the `-` with `\-`

Comment: No, it does not. See @Tim Pietzcker's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the -character for it to work (it's a regular expression syntax)

Try this:

```
"[\,@,+,\,?,\d,%,.,?,*,&,^,$,(,!,),#,\-,_]"
```